# SBC for webserver, compatible with Debian

Tags: linux, web-server, sbc

I’m looking for an **SBC (single board computer)** that can run Debian to use as a **webserver**.

Maximum budget is **€100 (120 $ / 85 £)**

### Requirements:

- Gigabit ethernet (it’s going to be a webserver)
- At least 1 USB port (2.0+)
- Can boot via USB
- Can run Debian out of the box (‘native’ Debian, can be an official port like Debian ARM64, but not ports like Armbian or Raspbian)

### Non-necessities:

- At least 1 video out port: (mini) HDMI, (mini) DP, DVI or VGA to access the terminal in case something goes wrong in the network and I can’t use SSH to get in)
- Capable of being powered through USB (micro) socket
- Ethernet not going over USB controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Orange Pi Plus 2](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepiplus2/)**

$49 (USD) on [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Orange-Pi-Plus-2-H3-Quad-Core-1-6GHZ-2GB-RAM-4K-Open-source-development-board/1553371_32516755321.html)

It has:

- 10/100/1000M Ethernet RJ45
- Four USB 2.0 HOST, one USB 2.0 OTG
- Support for Android, Ubuntu, *Debian*, Raspbian Image
- Supports HDMI output with HDCP

There might be other models (there is a slew of 'em) that fit the bill with more or less feature that you might want. This particular one has good power and features but might be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Olimex OLinuXino A20 - it is OSHWA certified, and works with regular Debian since years.

See [here](https://box.redpill.dk/hardware.html) my detailed recommendations for exactly which components to buy.

For alternatives in that same price range, see https://wiki.debian.org/CheapServerBoxHardware